# Youtube - Is it possible to pass a value from state for the autoplay value (React JS)

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

A requirement of mine is to autoplay a youtube video once in view, however, it seems that the onPlayerReady() function doesn't receive the prop in time so always defaults to false. I have tried multiple different approaches such as listening to that value in a useEffect and try to rerender the video, but not having any success.

Has anyone had a similar issue before? Or do I need to hook into a different event to update?

I will attach some sample code for visual reference, if more code needs adding to help with the problem please let me know!

```js
const initPlayer = new YT.Player(videoId, {
        height,
        width,
        videoId: youtubeId,
        frameborder: '0',
        playerVars: {
          modestbranding: 1,
          rel: 0,
          controls: 0
          mute: 1
          autoplay: autoplayWhenInView ? 1 : 0 // Would like to use this value which is passed from a parent component
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady, // autoplayWhenInView is false when it's actually true
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange || {},
        }
      });
```

Comment: Chrome (and maybe other browsers) made changes on when you're allowed to auto-play video's. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes (Though I'm not sure whether that has an impact on your usecase.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole component and then render it only when in view and then the `autoplay` will always be set to `true`.

Otherwise, you'll need to trigger programmatically the play method on the player instance as it was already created and `autoplay` is only for the initial initialization and not reactive.

Comment: Good shout, thanks, I will look to see if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, I got around this issue by conditionally rendering my video component when in view.